# jQuery how to append HTML in specific location

Tags: jquery

Hello I need to append this html during an onchange function.  Not sure what to access in the html so it knows where to be placed.

```
   var blueAsterik=$('<font color="blue" size="5">*&nbsp;</font>');
   <font color="blue" size="5">*&nbsp;</font>
```

to:

```
<td align="left" width="35%"><label for="asterik*" class="asterikLabel">place my asterik here :PLACE HERE </label></td>
```

It needs to go after the semicolon....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `append()` it will add it to the end of the selected element

```
var blueAsterik = $('<font color="blue" size="3">*&nbsp;</font>');
$('.asterikLabel').append(blueAsterik);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EjMfE/1**

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I know exactly how you're using it, but:

`$(".asterikLabel").append(blueAsterik);`

That is, assuming your label is really only going to look like:

`<label for="asterik" class="asterikLabel">place asterik here : </label>`

Now, if you need the "PLACE HERE" text to stay in place too, you would need to alter your HTML and jQuery:

```
<label for="asterik" class="asterikLabel">place asterik here :<span class="asterisk"></span>PLACE HERE </label>

$(".asterikLabel .asterisk").append(blueAsterik);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could do something like:

```
<td align="right" width="25%"><label for="asterik" class="asterikLabel">place asterik here: <span></span></label></td>
```

Then the js would look like:

```
$('.asterikLabel span').append(blueAsterik);
```